# Add custom key dynamically in array default idex key

Tags: php, arrays

**I have comma seperated array index key like (name) and (id) after getting query from group_concat like**

```
[name] = new,game
[id] = 1,2
```

**But after us exploid function for create array of comma seperated values**

**I got two array like this**

```
$array1 = array('0' => 'news', '1' => 'game');

Array
(
    [0] => news
    [1] => game
)

$array2 = array('0' => '1', '1' => '2');

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
```

**After use array map function I got final array**

```
$array3 = array_map(null, $array1, $array2);

$array3 = array(array('0'=>'new', '1'=>'1'),array('0'=>'game', '1'=>'2'));

    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => new
                [1] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => game
                [1] => 2
            )

    )
```

**But I need my final array like this**

```
$array3 = array(array('name'=>'new', 'id'=>'1'),array('name'=>'game', 'id'=>'2'));

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => new
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => game
            [id] => 2
        )

)
```

**I have tried this by loop and different array functions**

Comment: If you've tried things, show what you've tried and explain the problem with what you tried (how the actual result differed from the desired result).

Comment: Currently I removed all the stuff I have made at that time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am taking this from `array3`-

```
$array3 = array(array('0'=>'new', '1'=>'1'),array('0'=>'game', '1'=>'2'));
$result = array();

foreach($array3 as $key=>$value){
    $result[$key]["name"] = $value[0];
    $result[$key]["id"] = $value[1];
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: generally, generate an array implicitly is a bad practice, what about adding `if (!isset($result[$key])) $result[$key] = [];`?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to answer of @Sohel0415:

```
<?php

$array3 = array(array('0'=>'new', '1'=>'1'),array('0'=>'game', '1'=>'2'));

$result = array_map(function($a) {
    return ["name" => $a["0"], "id" => $a["1"]];
}, $array3);
print_r($result);
```

But, if I understand correctly, you start with `$name = ["game", "new"];` and 
`$id = ["1", "2"];`. If I am right:

```
<?php
$name = ["game", "new"];
$id = ["1", "2"];
$r = array_map(function($a1, $a2) {
    return ["name" => $a1, "id" => $a2];
},$name, $id);
print_r($r);
```

Do the desired effect.

Comment: Thnakyou, it make sense and helps me.